# Github Desktop not honouring pylint installed in a .venv

Tags: pylint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, github-desktop, pre-commit.com

I have a python project running in a virtual environment (created by poetry).

pylint is installed only in the virtual environment, not in the base.

pylint works well in the venv from command line, via pre-commit and inside Visual Studio Code which I start from the command line (poetry shell).

GitHub desktop cannot be started from the venv command line and when I try using it to commit my updated code it fails because the pre-commit hooks are launched and fail since it does not find pylint.

How to fix (other than installing pylint in the base env)?

Comment: the short answer is "you can't" -- the long answer is to instead use pylint from a pre-commit managed environment.  using it from a `language: system` hook is the unsupported escape hatch and it's on you to make sure that your tools are available in that case

Comment: @anthonysottile thanks. You drove the nails in the coffin :) As I mentioned pylint in the shell and from pre-commit work well. Shall just stop using Github desktop

Answer (score -2):

pre-commit try to use a separate virtualenv, you need to tell it to use the local venv with something like this:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre but pre-commit  is already like this and works perfectly from the command line. It's GitHub desktop not finding pylint ... unfortunately comments are unformatted but this is the .pre-commit-config.yaml section: -   repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: [--fail-under=8, --enable="W", --recursive=y, -rn,]

Comment: this is both not an answer and not a valid pre-commit configuration